# What is the best way to extract elements from jvalue scala?

Tags: scala

I am trying to extract elements from jvalue I tried to use below function but it does not work as expected when nested data:

My jvalue looks like this

```
JArray(List(JString({"schema":"contextschema",
    "data":[{"schema":"pgschema",
        "data":{"pageViewUUID":"c376e4e4-82516688f5f5"}},
        {"schema":"pageschema",
            "data":{"state":"active","environment":"dev",
                "client":"test",
                "clientConfigVersion":"1.4",
                "isAdBlock":false,
                "trackerVersion":"2.1.10",
                "screenOrientation":"landscape"}}]})))
```

I tried to make a function to extract but its not working as expected:

```
private def getElem(elem: String, json: JValue) = for {
    JObject(child) <- json
    JField(key, JString(value)) <- child if key == elem
  } yield value

println(getElem("client", dataJson).take(1).mkString(""))
```

Is there any best way in scala I can do it ?

Comment: You are using a JsString as the whole data, use Json.parse instead of JsString

Comment: You should use a Json library and map you data structure to a case class, usually that library do that for you behind the scenes if you do a correct setup. Take a look in here for example: `https://github.com/spray/spray-json`